# I am using django and my login form is not working

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a login form in index.html file and in same file I have login form by clicking in login button I want message to displayed you logged in and some buttons will visible. But I am not getting any response i view.py i tried to print something in terminal to check login_view is getting called or not but i got nothing. I am not getting any error message too.

My html code-

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login_view' %}" id="login-form">
                  
                <h5>Login Here</h5>
                {% csrf_token %} 
                <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" id="mail" name="email"><br>
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" id="loginpass" name="password"><br>
                <button id="login" type="submit">LOGIN</button><br>  
                </form>
```

my view.py code-

```
def login_view(request):
    print("View accessed")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']  
        password = request.POST['password'] 
        user = authenticate(request, email__iexact=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are logged in ')
            return redirect('home')  
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error in login.') 

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

my url code-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from PMP import views


from PMP import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
    path('', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
]
```

Comment: As far as I know, Ideally one should not be using the same url path (in this case for example "" [root url]) for two views. Please try once after updating your url paths with unique url.

Comment: Try changing last path pattern to `path('login/', views.login_view, name="login_view")`

Comment: Comment out the line `path('',views.home, name='home')`, and see if from there you can move forward.

Comment: right thanks  i needed to change the url path

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable message in your view which is displayed or not if the user is logged.

```
def login_view(request):
    print("View accessed")
    message=""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']  
        password = request.POST['password'] 
        user = authenticate(request, email__iexact=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages='You are logged in'
            return redirect('home')  
        else:
            messages='Invalid email or password.'
    else:
        messages= 'Error in login.'

    return render(request, 'index.html',{"message":message})
```

and in your Html file

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login_view' %}" id="login-form">
                  
                <h5>Login Here</h5>
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                   {{message}}{% endif 
                %}
                <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" id="mail" name="email"><br>
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" id="loginpass" name="password"><br>
                <button id="login" type="submit">LOGIN</button><br>  
                </form>
```